# Is it possible to make a string such as "G" equal a specific number like 50?

Tags: c

For example if I had the letter "B" in a array and want to count how many there are,could I make "B"=1 so I can easily count the number of b's.I do not think this is typecasting since I am do not want to make "B" itself = int B

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. If you mean just overwrite an array value, then the answer is it depends. If the array is not a literal string then yes, you can change the values in any manner you like as long as the new value fits within the type of the array.

Comment: Use an array whose indexes are the character codes, and the values are the counts.

Comment: If you just want to count a single character like `B`, you don't even need to do that. Just use a variable called `count`, and whenever you find a `B`, you increment `count`.

Comment: You seem to be failing to distinguish between strings and characters.  In C, they are very different things.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to assign to a string, just use an ordinary variable.

```
int b_count = 0;
char *string = "This is a B and this is another B";
for (char *p = string; *p != 0; p++) {
    if (*p == 'B') {
        b_count++;
    }
}
printf("There are %d B's in the string\n", b_count);
```